# Фаркоп - нормативне слово?

Tags: вживання-слів, іменники

Неодноразово чула вживання слова "фаркоп" для означення "пристроя на автомобілі для кріплення причіпа" (своїми словами).

Визначення знайшла на сайті магазина [Farkopmarket](http://farkopmarket.com.ua/index.php/uk/statti/85-dlia-choho-potriben-farkop.html)

> фаркоп – це тягово – зчіпний пристрій (ТЗП), який використовують для
>   зчеплення автомобіля з причіпом. Саме завдяки фаркопу  можна
>   перевозити вантажі які не вміщаються у багажник автомобіля.

Проте в жодному словнику слова "фаркоп" не знайшла.

Чи нормативно використовувати дане слово для письма?

Answer (score 4):

Читаємо [ПДР України](http://pdd.ua/ua/23/):

> Буксирування повинно виконуватися механічним транспортним засобом без
>   причепа і з технічно справними **зчіпними пристроями** як у
>   буксированого транспортного засобу, так і у транспортного засобу, що
>   буксирує.

Ось цей "зчіпний пристрій" і є фаркоп. А згідно з інформацією на сайті [Новобузької ЗОШ](http://ncpn.net.ua/dodatkove_obladnania.html) його ще називають "буксирний пристрій". Також можливим варіантом є "тягово-зчіпний пристрій" - сайт [BudTechnika](http://budtehnika.pp.ua/1807-tyagovo-zchpniy-pristry.html).